# Error using CurrentDb.Execute(sqlStr) despite SQL string functioning properly in query builder

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am building a MS Access database and I cannot find a solution to my issue anywhere.  All I want to do is trigger an update to my table using SQL code upon clicking a button, however, each time I try to run this code I get the error: "Run time error 3061, Too few parameters. Expected 1".  The naming of all the tables and fields I call in my SQL code is correct. I copy/pasted the SQL string from my debug print into a query builder and it worked without issue.  My code is:

```vb
Private Sub cmdAddRev_Click()
Dim compNum As String
Dim docPath As String
Dim filePath As String
Dim lastRev As Integer
Dim updateRev As Integer
Dim sqlStr As String


compNum = Me.cboRevSelection.Value
docPath = Me.tboRevDocLoc.Value
filePath = Me.tboRevFileLoc.Value
lastRev = DLookup("numLastRev", "tblComponents", "num = [Forms]![frmRevisor]![cboRevSelection]")
updateRev = lastRev + 1

sqlStr = " UPDATE tblComponents "
sqlStr = sqlStr & " SET numLastRev = " & updateRev
sqlStr = sqlStr & " WHERE num = [Forms]![frmRevisor]![cboRevSelection] "

CurrentDb.Execute (sqlStr) 'this line is flagged when the error happens


Debug.Print sqlStr

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
sqlStr = sqlStr & " WHERE num = [Forms]![frmRevisor]![cboRevSelection] "
```

to this:

```
sqlStr = sqlStr & " WHERE num = '" & [Forms]![frmRevisor]![cboRevSelection] & "'"
```

SQL from VBA, doesn't like parameters. Always use your references outside of the quotes, so that the query going to the execute already has values in it. (although using a parametized query would be better still...)

Comment: Thanks! This was very close to what I needed,  The only issue is that the value from cboRevSelection is a string, so I had to add single quotes around it.

Comment: edited my answer to reflect that.. curious though that you use the field name "num" (which i probably incorrectly assumed was short for "number") as a text field.

Comment: Gene, that was indeed a pretty misleading name, but this database is for mechanical parts/ assemblies whose "numbers" are often alphanumeric. So I am stuck defining part numbers as strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference a form when executing SQL via VBA. There are several options. Set a tempvar to the desired value and reference the tempvar in the SQL or create a public function referencing the form and use the function in the SQL

```
Public Function RevSelection()
RevSelection = [Forms]![frmRevisor]![cboRevSelection]
End Function
```

Then use

```
sqlStr = sqlStr & " WHERE num = RevSelection()"
```

or, the simplest, reference it as a value.

```
sqlStr = sqlStr & " WHERE num =" & [Forms]![frmRevisor]![cboRevSelection]
```

Comment: Maybe better like this:
sqlStr = sqlStr & " WHERE num = " & RevSelection()